# pow function in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, pow

I am implementing a math calculation in `Objective-C` in which i have used `pow(<#double#>, <#double#>)` function but it behaves weird.

I am trying to solve below math

```
  100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 3/12)/powf(1+0.0548, 3/12))
```

For same math, result of excel and xcode is different.

```
 Excel output = 100.01001 (correct)
 NSLog(@"-->%f",100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 3/12)/powf(1+0.0548, 3/12)));
 Xcode output = 100.045667 (wrong)
```

Now as everyone knows **`3/12 = 0.25`**.
 When i **replace** **`3/12`** with **`0.25`** in above math than xcode returns true result as below

```
 Excel output = 100.01001 (correct)
 NSLog(@"-->%f",100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 0.25)/powf(1+0.0548, 0.25)));
 Xcode output = 100.010095 (correct)
```

Anyone knows why `pow` function behave weird like this?  
**Note**: I have also used `powf` but behavior is still same.

Comment: *Now as everyone knows 3/12 = 0.25.* Not in any of the C-based languages. It's zero, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`3/12`, when you're doing *integer* math, is zero. In languages like, C, C++, ObjC and Java an expression like `x / y` containing only integers gives you an integral result, not a floating point one.

I suggest you try `3.0/12.0` instead.

The following C program (identical behaviour in this case to ObjC) shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void) {
    // Integer math.

    double d = 100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 3/12)/powf(1+0.0548, 3/12));
    printf ("%lf\n", d);

    // Just using zero as the power.

    d = 100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 0)/powf(1+0.0548, 0));
    printf ("%lf\n", d);

    // Using a floating point power.

    d = 100 *(0.0548/360*3+powf(1+0.0533, 3.0/12.0)/powf(1+0.0548, 3.0/12.0));
    printf ("%lf\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is (annotated):

```
100.045667 <= integer math gives wrong answer.
100.045667 <= the same as if you simply used 0 as the power.
100.010095 <= however, floating point power is okay.
```

Comment: @RahulPatel Every language has its own rules about integer vs. floating point division. Java and PHP are not the same as Objective C (or C which you're using here).

Comment: This is not related to iOS. It is related to the treatment of integers done by the compiler. The numeric literals 3 and 12 are treated as integers, so 3/12 is an integer division whose result is 0.

Comment: @RahulPatel: no, it's related to language. C and Objective C treat numbers in this way. Use the same code in C in Linux and you will see the same result as in iOS.

Comment: @RahulPatel, Java has the same rules as C/ObjC - `3/12` should give you zero. PHP, on the other hand, will give you `0.25`. It's a language-based thing. And Enrique is correct, this code was compiled and run on Linux.